Getting this error with Places API "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fE')"
I am having the issue when I try and use the Places API for address autocomplete in React with ts. When I run the project again the address autocomplete does fill out the address forms correctly but when I actually stay on that page and pick new address after new address and then refresh I start getting TypeErrors like the one mentioned in the title as well as this error You have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.
Following code resulting in the error:
declare global {
  interface Window {
    initMap: () => void;
  }
}

 window.initMap = window.initMap || (() => setGoogleMapsLoaded(true));

  const loader = new Loader({
    apiKey: import.meta.env.VITE_GOOGLE_MAP_IMBED_API_KEY,
    version: "weekly",
    libraries: ["places"],
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    loader.load().then(() => {
      setGoogleMapsLoaded(true);
    });
  }, []);

  const autocompleteInputRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (!isGoogleMapsLoaded || !autocompleteInputRef.current) return;

      try {
        if (
          !window.google ||
          !window.google.maps ||
          !window.google.maps.places
        ) {
          return "bad";
        }

        if (!autocompleteInputRef.current) return;

        const autocomplete = new window.google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
          autocompleteInputRef.current,
          {
            types: ["address"],
            componentRestrictions: { country: "us" },
          }
        );
        console.log(autocomplete);

        autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
          const place = autocomplete.getPlace();
          if (!place || !place.address_components) return;

          const streetAddress1Component = place.address_components.find(
            (component) => component.types.includes("street_number")
          );
          const streetAddress2Component = place.address_components.find(
            (component) => component.types.includes("route")
          );
          const cityComponent = place.address_components.find((component) =>
            component.types.includes("locality")
          );
          const stateComponent = place.address_components.find((component) =>
            component.types.includes("administrative_area_level_1")
          );
          const zipCodeComponent = place.address_components.find((component) =>
            component.types.includes("postal_code")
          );

          if (
            !streetAddress1Component ||
            !streetAddress2Component ||
            !cityComponent ||
            !stateComponent ||
            !zipCodeComponent
          ) {
            // Fallback mechanism to parse the full address
            const fullAddress = place.formatted_address
              ? place.formatted_address.split(", ")
              : [];
            setFormData({
              ...formData,
              streetAddress1: fullAddress[0] || "",
              city: fullAddress[1] || "",
              state: fullAddress[2]?.split(" ")[0] || "",
              zipCode: fullAddress[2]?.split(" ")[1] || "",
            });
          } else {
            const streetAddress1 = streetAddress1Component.long_name;
            const streetAddress2 = streetAddress2Component.long_name;
            const city = cityComponent.long_name;
            const state = stateComponent.short_name;
            const zipCode = zipCodeComponent.long_name;

            setFormData({
              ...formData,
              streetAddress1: `${streetAddress1} ${streetAddress2}`,
              city,
              state,
              zipCode,
            });
          }
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    })();
  }, [isGoogleMapsLoaded, autocompleteInputRef.current]);

Like I said with the current code I have there it does work properly sometimes but other times it starts giving me the TypeError and then just stops working completely.

You're not checking the value of isGoogleMapsLoaded in your second effect hook.

@Phil I went ahead and added this if (!isGoogleMapsLoaded) return; in the second useEffect and still running into the same error, did I do this incorrectly or is there something I am missing?

You might be interested in a pre-built integration like https://visgl.github.io/react-google-maps/. At the least, you could look at the project source code to see what they do

@Phil thank you for the help, I did some ore research and found that using Loader was the solution to my use case for this. I appreciate the suggestion and think yours would have worked too, thank you!

I ended up going with a different library completely when finding a solution to this. As you can see in the updated code I used Loader which worked better in my use case.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
